# Unable to compile C++17 with clang++ on Mac OSX

Tags: c++, macos, g++, c++17, clang++

clang++ version:

```
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Trying some C++ parallelism:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <math.h>

#define N 10000000

double myFunction(double x) {
    return pow(x, x) / (int(x) % 3);
}

int main() {
    std::random_device rd;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double> uniform(0.0, 20.0);

    std::vector<double> inputs;
    std::vector<double> returnValues;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        double r = uniform(rd);
        inputs.push_back(r);
    }

    std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq,
                    inputs.begin(), inputs.end(), 
                    returnValues.begin(), 
                    myFunction);
}
```

I have tried compiling with all of these:

```sh
$ clang++ -std=c++1z go.cpp -o run
$ clang++ -std=c++17 go.cpp -o run
```

with and without `#include <optional>`. But all come up with same compiler errors:

```
go.cpp:93:25: error: no member named 'execution' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'exception'?
    std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq,
                   ~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
                        exception
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/exception:97:29: note: 'exception' declared here
class _LIBCPP_EXCEPTION_ABI exception
                            ^
go.cpp:93:36: error: no member named 'par_unseq' in 'std::exception'
    std::transform(std::execution::par_unseq,
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [parallel] Error 1
```

EDIT:

Trying with `gcc` doesn't work either:

```sh
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
$ gcc -ltbb -std=c++17 go.cpp -o run
$ gcc -ltbb go.cpp -o run
```

generate the error:

```
go.cpp:69:10: fatal error: 'execution' file not found
#include <execution>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 8):

If you look at the [compiler support page on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), you'll notice Apple Clang still doesn't support parallel algorithms.

Comment: OK, how can I best make it compile?

Comment: Use GCC, or just libstdc++

Comment: @ZuodianHu you mean still compile with clang by link to libstdc++?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing

```
#include<algorithm>
#include<execution>
```

That being said, according to the compiler [support overview at cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) Apple Clang does not yet have support for the parallel algorithms extensions. (Look for "Parallelism TS" on the page.)

Comment: ah I see. i’m very new to c++ does that mean I will have to use a different compiler? I think g++ is a symlink to clang++. is it wisest to install a new version of clang++ ? or will that mess up my apple system? I like the quality of error messages in clang

Comment: @lollercoaster I don't really know. If libstdc++ and libtbb are installed on the system, the compiler flags `-stdlib=libstdc++ -ltbb` might be enough to make it compile with Clang. Otherwise try to install GCC and libtbb, then the flag `-ltbb` should be enough. And yes, on MacOS, `g++` is a link to `clang++`. So you have Clang, but the standard library of Clang (libc++) does not seem to support it yet. The standard library of the *actual* GCC (libstdc++) does however (in combination with libtbb).

Comment: hm, this doesn't seem to work: `gcc -ltbb -std=c++17 go.cpp -o run`. compile error: `fatal error: 'execution' file not found #include <execution>`

Comment: @lollercoaster It should be `g++`, not `gcc` (which is for C, not C++). But you need to make sure that `g++` is *actually* the `g++` from GCC, not Clang, or you need to at least add the `-stdlib=libstdc++` flag (again, no guarantee that this works). In your edit to the answer `gcc` is still a link to `clang` (the same way that `g++` is a link to `clang++`)